# Stop google array formula from expanding sheet to 50,000 rows

Tags: google-sheets

I've got an array formula which I've managed to put together as this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(B:B)=1,"Status",(if(D:D="","",IF(D:D<today(),CONCAT("Overdue by ",(TODAY()-D:D) & " days"),IF(D:D<TODAY()+30,CONCAT("Due in ",(TODAY()-D:D) & " days"),if(D:D>today(),"Not Due","")))))))
```

For some reason it expands the sheet much larger than I need it with blank cells. I only need it to a max of 500. Any ideas how I'd stop this from happening?

Comment: Use proper ranges then: A1:A500 D1:D500

Comment: This error was occurring with me, thanks for asking this. I upvoted your question.

Comment: I have a related but slightly different question: what if we want this to be a helper column, with an arbitrary number of items, which will then be filtered to appear in the final column; is there a way for Sheets to internally have access to those values without visually expanding the number of row in our sheet?

Answer (score 3):

In extremis you might wrap your formula in [ARRAY_CONSTRAIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036) and predefine the maximum number of rows and columns:

```
=array_constrain(ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(B:B)=1,"Status",(if(D:D="","",IF(D:D<today(),CONCAT("Overdue by ",(TODAY()-D:D) & " days"),IF(D:D<TODAY()+30,CONCAT("Due in ",(TODAY()-D:D) & " days"),if(D:D>today(),"Not Due",""))))))),500,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Late with the answer, but I've noticed that `ArrayFormula` starts expanding sheet only if the formula is not in the same row as the first cell you're targeting, so in your case `B:B` - `ArrayFormula` should be placed in first row, for `B2:B` - it should be placed in the second row.

Note: this behaviour only applies to to ArrayFormulas that store nested functions such as `IF` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the pointers in this thread. I had an arrayformula that started:

```
=arrayformula(if(A3:A="","",[do stuff()]))
```

The formula created 50,000 rows which slowed everything to a crawl.

I edited it to constrain the array to 996 rows thusly:

```
=arrayformula(if(A3:A999="","",[do stuff()]))
```

All was well and the sheet was fast as lightning again

Answer (score 0):

You probably have that formula in more than one cell, and it seems it should only be in the first row of whichever column you want it to be in.

Comment: I've got the formula in the top cell which prints the heading out "status" then runs the array down from there. I've check to make sure i dont have it anywhere else and I don't.

Comment: @RB Unfortunately, the only way I can reproduce your issue is by copying your formula into an additional cell.